# Youtube Iframe no fullscreen button

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, youtube

Maybe it's Friday afternoon kicking in but for some reason I seem unable to get a fullscreen button to appear on my embedded Youtube videos. All I'm doing is copying the share code which is generated from a Youtube video:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/hFoQVx8ZcHo?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

So for example with this code http://jsfiddle.net/chricholson/v8sjL/ I see:

[image]

I found some articles which said about the URL being wrong `/v/[code]` rather than `/embed/[code]` but copying directly from Youtube I thought I'd be safe.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It seems I needed a number of changes, final code:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/hFoQVx8ZcHo?rel=0&fs=1" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>​
```

Firstly, the URL needs `&fs=1`, this triggers the button to show. Additionally, `webkitallowfullscreen` and `mozallowfullscreen` are needed, stating the obvious these solve browser specific problems.

One interesting thing I did find, despite having the working code, this sample DOES NOT work through jsfiddle, presumably something to do with being inside of an iframe. See http://jsfiddle.net/mrchris2013/v8sjL/5/ for what I mean.

Comment: the "?fs=1" part doesn't seem to be necessary. On the latest Chrome, it will work will allowfullscreen alone; I guess other browsers may need webkitallowfullscreen and/or mozallowfullscreen

Answer (score 4):

solved...! if you have an iframe(youtube) inside an iframe(jsfiddle) inside main HTML you need to define

`webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen`

to both the iframes in order for it to work.....

Comment: Firefox insists the inner iframe set the `allowFullScreen` attribute. Merely setting `allow: fullscreen` is not enough, in spite of what it says [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-allowfullscreen):  'allowfullscreen ... is considered a legacy attribute and redefined as allow="fullscreen" '

Answer (score 3):

The fullscreen option came back expect I had to remove `&fs=1` at the end of the link.

```
<iframe width="1280" height="720" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/doXntJaJ-nQ" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: It seems to me that this is the correct answer, not the currently accepted one