# Full screen in embedded videos from Youtube

Tags: html, iframe

I want to see a screen full of embedded video but i am getting black borders on left and right but i have included allow full screen in my coding also.How to remove the borders and see stretched video? I am attaching my code and screen shot .![Screen shot of the borders`<iframe id="vid" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RdIh8GiVR9I?autoplay=1&amp;modestbranding=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;rel=0&amp;allowfullscreen=true"></iframe></div>`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7LdR.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is slightly more complicated.
The "allowfullscreen" is just there for displaying the "fullscreen" button. (Although [it's kind of strange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12217827/youtube-iframe-no-fullscreen-button))

To make it behave like you want to, **have a look at [this explanation](https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php)**
(The section with "`<iframe>`")

Basically, you need to put the video in a div with the full width of the website (what you probably already did) and some css magic to make it the correct height.