# Fullscreen is not working on my website

Tags: html, youtube

This is the code:

```
<iframe width="400" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4HXFnO5yW0U" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

However, the results are these:

[The fullscreen button is disabled for some reason](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aonRu.png)

Anybody knows what is wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12217827/youtube-iframe-no-fullscreen-button

Comment: Not really, @piscator.
I **can** see the fullscreen button, it's just not working.
UPDATE: I've read what this post said and did it, it is still unavailable

Comment: Cannot reproduce — http://test-cases.dorward.me.uk/stackoverflow/34384669/ — the button fullscreens it for me there.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [youtube support article](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6276924?hl=en), the reason the button is disabled could be:

1. Your browser permissions linked to full screen youtube videos
2. Your browser addons or extensions preventing the functionality

I've tried the code on `Google Chrome v47.0.2526.106`, and the full screen button seems to be working fine.

You could try using another video URL and see if that works, then you'll have a clearer idea of the issue

Comment: I've already read this article before I post this, I will try though.

Answer (score -1):

Update Code and try

From

```
<iframe width="400" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4HXFnO5yW0U" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

To

```
<iframe width="400" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4HXFnO5yW0U" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Alternatelly try css

```
embed,
iframe,
object {
    max-width: 100%!important;
    max-height: 100%!important;
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this can fix everything.
It's not working either.